# Can ElasticSearch aggregations do what SQL can do?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In Elasticsearch I need get the frequency and the number of colors that occur the most frequent from the highest to lowest.
If I have data like this:

```
id|name
----------
1|blue
----------
2|blue
----------
3|green
----------
4|yellow
----------
5|blue
----------
6|yellow
----------
7|purple
----------
8|purple
----------
9|purple
```

I need to get the count of each color and then group by the count.  So in the end, I would like all the colors that occurs the same number of times to be inside one group.
This is how I would do it in sql.

```
select 
  count(*) as 'Number of Colors', 
  i.c as 'Seen times' 
from 
    (
      select
        name as 'n', 
        count(*) as 'c'
      from
        colors
      group by name
   ) i 
group by i.c
order by i.c desc;
```

This would return:

```
Number of Colors | Seen times
------------------------------
2                | 3
------------------------------
1                | 2
------------------------------
1                | 1
```

How would I write it in Elasticsearch query? I am using version 5.5.

Comment: what Elasticsearch query?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/_introducing_the_query_language.html

Comment: The result table is wrong, the numbers in the left and right columns should be swapped, i.e. 3 colors seen 2 times, 2 colors seen 1 time and 1 color seen 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripted_metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) with painless script

## Query

I will explain it in more details below.

```
POST index/type/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "colorgroups": {
"scripted_metric": {
"init_script" : "params._agg.transactions = [:]",
"map_script": "params.key = doc['colorname'].value; if(params._agg.transactions[params.key] == null){   params._agg.transactions[params.key] = 1; }else{   params._agg.transactions[params.key] ++ }",
"combine_script": "return params._agg.transactions;",
"reduce_script": "params.color_counters =[:]; params.groups_counters =[:]; for(shard_result in params._aggs){   for(color_name in shard_result.keySet()){     if(params.color_counters[color_name] == null){       params.color_counters[color_name] = shard_result[color_name]     }else{       params.color_counters[color_name] = params.color_counters[color_name] + shard_result[color_name]     }    } }  for(color_name in params.color_counters.keySet()){   params.group_counter = params.color_counters[color_name].toString();   if(params.groups_counters[params.group_counter] == null){     params.groups_counters[params.group_counter] = 1   }else{     params.groups_counters[params.group_counter] ++   } }  return params.groups_counters"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Result

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "colorgroups": {
      "value": {
        "2": 3,
        "1": 2,
        "1": 1
     }
    }
  }
}
```

## init_script

init some values to keep intermediate results

```
params._agg.transactions = [:]
```

## map_script

Calculations for each document. Try to keep it small and reduce as much data as possible on this step.

```
params.key = doc['colorname'].value;
if(params._agg.transactions[params.key] == null){
  params._agg.transactions[params.key] = 1;
}else{
  params._agg.transactions[params.key] ++
}
```

## combine_script

Calculations for each shard. We already did everything in map_script, just return hash map

```
return params._agg.transactions
```

## reduce_script

Working with partial aggregations from each shard. We need to merge them into one HashMap first. And group by counter value after

```
params.color_counters =[:];
params.groups_counters =[:];
//merging all partial aggregations to params.color_counters
for(shard_result in params._aggs){
  for(color_name in shard_result.keySet()){
    if(params.color_counters[color_name] == null){
      params.color_counters[color_name] = shard_result[color_name]
    }else{
      params.color_counters[color_name] = params.color_counters[color_name] + shard_result[color_name]
    } 
  }
}

//Grouping by color counter to params.groups_counters
for(color_name in params.color_counters.keySet()){
  params.group_counter = params.color_counters[color_name].toString();
  if(params.groups_counters[params.group_counter] == null){
    params.groups_counters[params.group_counter] = 1
  }else{
    params.groups_counters[params.group_counter] ++
  }
}

return params.groups_counters
```

You can call

```
Debug.explain(variable);
```

anywhere in the painless script to debug a variable and adjust script for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

By default elastic search do not provide any aggregation type which uses 
 some aggregation results to give output of new set of aggregations like SQL has.

1. One way of doing it is to have terms aggregation and then group them
   using a script
2. If you want to achieve this in single query, you can use **Scripted Metric Aggregation** to achieve this, use below link to get more details :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html