# Terms aggregation on multiple fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get some counts from Elasticsearch. I have a query:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "first-metadata": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "filters.metadata.first-metadata"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and as a response I'm getting something like that:

```
"aggregations": {
  "first-metadata": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": 87000,
        "doc_count": 2
      },
      {
        "key": 100000,
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Everything is like I've expected. But the problem is that I have multiple metadata types: `first-metadata`, `second-metadata` and `third-metadata` and I would like to have something like that:

```
"aggregations": {
  "first-metadata": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": 87000,
        "doc_count": 2
      },
      {
        "key": 100000,
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "second-metadata": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": 5555,
        "doc_count": 24
      },
      {
        "key": 2222,
        "doc_count": 14
      },
      {
        "key": 3333,
        "doc_count": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  "third-metadata": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": 7777,
        "doc_count": 23
      },
      {
        "key": 3333,
        "doc_count": 11
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve such results in one aggregation query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple

```
POST index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "first-metadata": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "filters.metadata.first-metadata"
      }
    },
    "second-metadata": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "filters.metadata.second-metadata"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed this is simple :) Thanks. But I have a more difficult case. What if there are thousands of metadata? I need to repeat this thousands times for each field? Or other case: the metadata names are auto generated and I would like to get terms aggregations for all of them. Can I do this with wildcard (`filters.metadata.*`) or somehow?

Comment: It is possible. Check my answer with map-reduce implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413369/can-elasticsearch-aggregations-do-what-sql-can-do/48673991#48673991 It will give you an idea what you can do. Fill free to ask if you need more details or have any questions.